# Необходимо ,для созданной по ходу работы программы, кнопки установить процедуру onclick для чего я хочу создать процедуру, но безуспешно

Tags: функции, lazarus

```
procedure a(sender: TObject; Banka: TImage; 
  Button4: TButton; Button5: TButton; Button6: TButton; Button7: TButton);
begin
  Banka.Left:=Banka.round(Left+Form4.Left/4);
end;
```

Lazarus выдает ошибку! Я не понимаю в чем мой промах?

Answer (score 0):

```
procedure TForm4.SomeMethod;
var 
  btn: TButton;
begin
  btn := TButton.Create(self);
  ...
  btn.OnClick = a;
end;

procedure TForm4.a(sender: TObject);
begin
  Banka.Left := Banka.Round(Left + self.Left / 4);
end;
```

Comment: Спасибо, но Lazarus ругается на первую строчку в вашем коде. Говорит, что ожидается ";" , но найдена " ." .

Comment: @KIRILL В каком файле находится класс `TForm4`?

Comment: В этом же файле

Comment: @KIRILL Вставьте в вопрос больше кода.